# How to copy file from AWS S3 bucket into Azure blob storage

Tags: azure, go, amazon-s3

I'm trying to copy files from AWS S3 bucket into Azure blob storage via Golang application.

I used `Azcopy` command via Azure powershell and it worked.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-s3

I'm trying to use it in Golang application.
I searched for `Azcopy` equivalent in Azure SDK.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/tree/main/sdk/storage/azblob

I don't want to download the file and upload him to reduce transfer time and costs.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used Go so I won't be able to give you exact code but here's what you would need to do:

1. Create pre-signed URL of the object in S3. Please ensure that the URL has `Read` permissions.
2. Use copy blob functionality to copy the object from S3 to Azure blob storage. The method you would want to use is [`StartCopyFromURL`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/blob/58ac9ec45a4806d774bc0b647f30c1bb39091a7a/sdk/storage/azblob/blob/client.go#L212).

Please note that copy blob is an asynchronous server-side operation so keep the expiry of pre-signed URL long enough for the copy operation to complete. You can read more about copy operation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/copy-blob?tabs=microsoft-entra-id.

Comment: Why should I have create pre-signed URL with permissions from S3? Shouldn't I just supply the object URL?

Comment: If your object is publicly accessible, then you do not need pre-signed URL however if it is not, then you will need a pre-signed URL for the object. This is needed because Azure Storage service should be able to read the object.

Comment: Don't pre-signed URL just create an expiry on top of the generated URL?

Comment: Not just expiry but also permissions. Using pre-signed URLs, you can do a lot of things like uploading, deleting, reading etc. depending on what permissions are included in the pre-signed URL.

Comment: Thanks on it. It worked but doesn't work in scale really well. Does any equivalent to multi part upload from URL in azure?

Comment: Can you explain the scaling part not working well? It would be better if you ask a separate question for what's not working for you.

Comment: I opened a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77678021/copy-large-files-from-aws-s3-bucket-into-azure-blob-via-golang-application