# Copy large files from AWS S3 bucket into Azure blob via golang application

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I'm trying to copy large files (GBs/TBs size) from AWS S3 bucket to Azure blob storage via Golang application.

I found out from Azure SDK the option to use [StartCopyFromURL](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/blob/58ac9ec45a4806d774bc0b647f30c1bb39091a7a/sdk/storage/azblob/blob/client.go#L212) and the copy operation worked but for 10GB file, it took ~10 minutes.

I searched for the eqvivalent of AWS Multi upload from another bucket as a source but didn't find.

I would appreciate help with a solution to copy large files from AWS S3 bucket into Azure blob.

Comment: If that command directly retrieves data from a URL (eg Amazon S3 pre-signed URL) and stores in Azure, then it's the best option. The alternative would be to **download** the object from S3 and then **upload** to Azure, which would be much slower. There is also [Copy data from Amazon S3 to Azure Storage by using AzCopy | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-s3) but I don't know which method that uses.

Comment: We need to copy the file, in azure SDK, I only found an option to copy it from URL. The best option should be a multi upload via Azure SDK. Download+Upload 1TB file is going to be very slow and cost a lot of money for multiple files.

Comment: In any way, the file needs to be downloaded and then uploaded - you can't get around that. The bytes need to move. The question of speed is regarding how you can parallelise multiple requests or if this is one huge file, split it up and use [Azure Block Blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-block-blobs--append-blobs--and-page-blobs#about-block-blobs) (Azure equivalent of multi-part files in AWS) to upload parts independently. There's a few ways here but it's not clear if the issue is cost or time and how many files you have.

Comment: If by 'AWS Multi upload' you mean a multi-part upload, then block blobs as linked in my comment above is the way forward.

Answer (score 0):

I had some experience with two solutions, so it is up to your project's needs in terms of timelines, one-time need or a long-term sync, and so on...
One is Rclone which is free, ( https://rclone.org/ ) - it is a CLI based tool
The second is Netapp CloudSync (https://bluexp.netapp.com/cloud-sync-service) with a simple UI admin interface